# Parsing the Logic of turned = !turned In A Simple Flip Card JS Function

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of reviewing a fairly straightforward ES6 implementation of a [clickable, double-sided flashcard](https://codepen.io/cahdeemer/pen/oJdzRa) on Codepen.

I'm able to parse 99% of the code, but this `toggleTurn` function has left me scratching my head.

Specifically, I'm wondering:

(1) What is the purpose of setting the `turned` value to to its logical opposite (`!turned`) at the beginning of this function?

(2) Why is it necessary to pass the `event` object to this function as a parameter?  Wouldn't it be simpler & easier to just invoke a `toggleTurn()` function within an event listener?

```
function toggleTurn(e) {
  turned = !turned;
  if (turned) {
    this.classList.add("turned");
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("turned");
  }
}
```

I'm sure the answers here are blindly obvious, so many thanks in advance for the time & patience!

Comment: the turned variable is coming from the lexical scope. your code must be setting this in their execution context. passing event is not necessary, however firefox required it chrome does not.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of setting the turned value to to its logical
> opposite (!turned) at the beginning of this function?

If the `"turned"` class is added on the html element, then that means `turned` is true. Negating its value will give `false` which will execute the `else` block.

Similarly, if the `"turned"` class is not added on the html element, then that means `turned` is false. Negating its value will give `true` which will execute the `if` block.

You could simplify the function using the [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method:

```
function toggleTurn() {
  this.classList.toggle("turned");
}
```

> Why is it necessary to pass the event object to this function as a
> parameter? Wouldn't it be simpler & easier to just invoke a
> toggleTurn() function within an event listener?

If it's not used in the function, then it's not needed. You can remove it if you want to. It does however serve as a reminder that the function is used as an event listener.

Comment: You were quicker.

Comment: GRMA.  This makes sense! I was getting the basic logical mechanics (set the `turned` value to its opposite, i.e. set true to false and false to true), but was failing to see how the if/else conditional logic of this function factored into this.  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @iamthelabhras many people don't know that `classList.toggle()` method exists, I'm seeing this kind of conditional often. But please keep in mind that there are many situations, where having the state kept as pure variables makes more sense and is easier to maintain. But for simple scenarios, you can base your logic on the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

In this code it makes no sense to have the `turned` variable, because it's only being used to toggle the class name. In fact, the `toggleTurn()` function could just be a one-liner:

```js
function toggleTurn(e) {
  this.classList.toggle("turned");
}
```

And as for the `e`, as you can see it's not in use. Event listeners automatically get the `event` parameter and there are different philosophies of whether you should include unused parameters in your function definition or not. There's nothing wrong with keeping it in there.

Comment: GRMA to you as well, Robo Robok, for clarifying (1) how this function's code could be made more concise using the inbuilt `toggle` method and (2) that there are different schools of thought regarding unused parameters like the `e` object.

This is one of the many pitfalls of trying to extend one's knowledge using Codepens:  they're not as rigorously reviewed as StackOverflow posts!